# Django RF. How to have a serializer take in objects from 2 models? or to have a functionality like a formset in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Hey guys I am completely new in django rest framework, I have this post and postimages model which has a foreign key relation with post, this is in normal django, a formset where we can upload multiple images. How can I do a similar thing with django rf? I have this serializer, how do I implement this relation?
also in the detail view, only the image which is in the post model is showing and is completely ignoring the postimage model.

Can someone show an example or point to a simple source where it is easy to understand?

these are the codes:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    post_date = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id','title', 'post_date', 'updated', 'image', 'slug', 'user',] # the image in this field is of Post model

class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ['post', 'images',] # in django this is a formset


def create_post_api_view(request):

    user = request.user
    post = Post(user=user)

    serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def detail_post_api_view(request, slug):

    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    serializer = PostSerializer(post)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**EDIT:**
I have slightly changed the fields on `PostSerializer` where I added postimage_set also, which now looks like this:

```
['id','title', 'post_date', 'updated', 'image', 'likes', 'slug', 'not_comment', 'favourite', 
                'visibility', 'user', 'postimage_set']
```

the rest every code is same..but i am getting the output of postimage as its id's 1, 2, 3 rather than the image. How to change that?

```
{
"id": 3,
"title": "Test Post!",
"post_date": "2020-07-22T13:39:43.607968Z",
"updated": "2020-07-22T15:39:43.607968+02:00",
"image": "/media/postimage/0.jpg",
"slug": "test-post",
"user": "testuser1234",
"postimage_set": [
    1,
    2
]
```

}

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  454.             return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  94.                 instance = getattr(instance, attr)

During handling of the above exception ('Post' object has no attribute 'post_image'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py" in handler
  50.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\danny\Project\Website\posts\api\views.py" in detail_post_api_view
  48.   return Response(serializer.data)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  562.         ret = super().data

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  260.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  516.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  487.             raise type(exc)(msg)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/posts/3/beliver/view/
Exception Value: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `post_image` on serializer `PostSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'post_image'.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships
You need something like the following:

````
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ['post', 'image',] # in django this is a formset```


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    post_date = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    post_image = PostImageSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id','title', 'post_date', 'updated', 'image', 'slug', 'user', 'post_image'] # the image in this field is of Post model
````

Comment: thanks for the response and the resource material.. but i am getting an error here..The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'post_image'.

Comment: Hello, can you please check out my edited question too? Thanks

Comment: Didn't get you there, could you post the full traceback and updated code?

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question with the traceback.

Comment: Maybe try `post_image = PostImageSerializer(many=True)` since Post and PostImages seem to have a one to many relation.